# Asp.net Core 2 [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

My MVC project is multiple languages, Other link work well, but when I take action with [`Authorize`], is raises

> 404 error

How to override `OnAuthorization` method on Asp.net Core2

Comment: `code` routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{culture=en-US}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); `code`

Comment: [Authorize] redirect error url , http://localhost:3817/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2Fhi-IN%2FHome%2FReports

Comment: right url should be , http://localhost:3817/en-US/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2Fen-US%2FHome%2FReports

Answer (score 0):

Remove the filter from method, method add:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    return View();
else
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
```